# Marginal effects from random effects multinomial logit with Stata

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, multinomial

I have data in which participants pick one of three options for a number of related questions. For one part of the analysis, I have combined all of these answers, so that I have a number of observations from each participant. The way I have modeled this is with a multinomial logit with the participant ID as a random effect. I have then estimated the model using `gllamm`.

Where I've now been stuck for a while is that I cannot seem to extract marginal effects from this regression. My searches so far suggest that the way to do it involves `gllapred, mu marg`. Running that, however, seems to return the overall probability of picking a particular choice in my sample. Rather, I'd like to find out how a change in one of my dummy variables (e.g. male) changes the probability of making that particular choice.

Assuming there is no way to get anything like the output of `margins` for this type of object, is there a way I can get the marginal effects manually? That is, can I estimate at male = 0, male = 1, then take the difference? My variables of interest are dummies, but I do have a continuous variable (age) that I presumably could not estimate like this -- however, I'm also not all that interested in the marginal effect of that.

Comment: How is your model specified, and did you use the `expanded` option? It would really help if there are data and code since `gllamm` is not the most straightforward program.

Comment: Meanwhile, even for `gllamm` I think you can always use `mat list e(b)` to manually extract the coefficients and derive the difference from there. Since it is multinominal logit model, you will need to determine the values at which other covariates are fixed. And don't forget to take the exponential!

Comment: I did not use (or know of?) the expanded option for `gllamm`, but I since fixed my problem by building the same model as a generalized structural equation model, using `gsem`. Unlike `gllamm`, I can follow that with `margin, dydx(*)`. Code is quite a bit uglier/longer, but the results are the same (as one would hope!). Thanks for the suggestions about expanded and extracting via `e(b)`, I'm sure that will come in handy in the future!

Comment: `gsem` is a good alternative, although the conceptualization and code are probability both more tedious. Whether to use `expanded` or not is tied to how random effects are specified. Intuitively, I think separate random intercepts for each response should be used in multilevel and multinominal models. An example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also learning about `gllamm` and finally got around to making this small example that hopefully helps the discussion (even though it is too late for the OP's original need).

The example does three things:

1. uses results from `e(b)` to calculate the marginal effect of a
   dichotomous variable (on the odds ration; some tweak needed for
   probabilities;
2. demonstrates results from the `gllapred varname,
   mu marg`approach, which is not desired for our interest;
3. compares the expanded method that estimates separate (and correlated) random
   effects for different responses and the "naive" method that produces
   only one random intercept.

A useful reference for this type of models is section 9.3 from an earlier [manual](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~fdominic/teaching/bio656/software/gllamm.manual.pdf) of `gllamm`.

First some fake data. Hope this fits the OP's description.

```
clear
set more off
input id q1 q2 q3 q4 age female
1 3 1 2 3 10 1
2 3 1 2 3 12 0 
3 3 3 1 1 11 0
4 1 1 2 3 9  1
5 1 3 1 1 10 1
6 2 3 1 2 11 1
7 2 1 1 3 11 1
8 2 1 3 3 11 1
9 1 2 3 1 11 1
10 1 2 3 1 11 1
11 2 1 3 2 12 0
12 3 1 1 2 12 1
13 2 1 2 3 12 0
14 2 1 1 1 12 0
15 3 2 1 1 12 0
end
reshape long q, i(id) j(item)
```

This is a "naive" model that only produces one random effect variance despite separate estimated for the outcome of response=2 (versus 1), and response=3 (versus 1).

```
gllamm q age female,i(id) link(mlogit) family(binomial) base(1)
```

As the OP pointed out, the `gllapred varname, mu marg` approach basically predicts the probabilities for every individual on each response. Despite the similar name, this is different from Stata's `margins` command.

```
// The -gllapred- approach
gllapred x1,outcome(1) mu marginal
gllapred x2,outcome(2) mu marginal
gllapred x3,outcome(3) mu marginal
sort id item
list id item q x1 x2 x3 // same probability for the same individual; x1+x2+x3=1
```

But we can manually estimate the marginal effect of `female` when other covariates are fixed using results from `e(b)`. First, we find out the mean of age.

```
// fix age at mean
su age, meanonly // average age
loca mean_age=r(mean)
```

Then we subtract the two predicted odds ratios manually for each response.

```
// response: c2
loca c2m=exp(_coef[c2:age]*`mean_age'+_coef[c2:_cons])
loca c2f=exp(_coef[c2:age]*`mean_age'+_coef[c2:female]+_coef[c2:_cons])
loca diffc2=`c2f'-`c2m'
di "c2[OR_female - OR_male]=>" %5.3g `c2f' " -" %5.3g `c2m' " =" %5.3g `diffc2'  // "OR" for odds ratio

// response: c3
loca c3m=exp(_coef[c3:age]*`mean_age'+_coef[c3:_cons])
loca c3f=exp(_coef[c3:age]*`mean_age'+_coef[c3:female]+_coef[c3:_cons])
loca diffc3=`cf'-`c3m'
di "c3[OR_female - OR_male]=>" %5.3g `c3f' " -" %5.3g `c3m' " =" %5.3g `diffc3'  // "OR" for odds ratio
```

Next, we apply the expanded model that produces the same fixed effect estimates but two variances for the random effects plus their covariance.

```
sort id item
gen patt=_n
expand 3                            // triple number of cases
sort patt
rename q response                   // just to match help file
by patt, sort: gen alt=_n           // create all three potential answers
gen chosen=response==alt            // mark the case with the chosen answer
qui tab alt, gen(it)
eq i2: it2
eq i3: it3

gllamm alt age female,i(id) nrf(2) eqs(i2 i3) nip(4) expanded(patt chosen m) /*
*/ link(mlogit) family(binomial) trace // compare the random effects to the "naive" model
```

The fixed effects are the same as the last model, but note that there are now two more random effect parameters. Code in the last model can be used to calculate the marginal effect of `female`.

```
// fix age at mean
su age, meanonly
loca mean_age=r(mean)

// c2
loca c2m=exp(_coef[c2:age]*`mean_age' + _coef[c2:_cons])
loca c2f=exp(_coef[c2:age]*`mean_age' + _coef[c2:female]+_coef[c2:_cons])
loca diffc2=`c2f'-`c2m'
di "c2[OR_female - OR_male]=>" %5.3g `c2f' " -" %5.3g `c2m' " =" %5.3g `diffc2'  // "OR"=>odds ratio

// c3
loca c3m=exp(_coef[c3:age]*`mean_age' + _coef[c3:_cons])
loca c3f=exp(_coef[c3:age]*`mean_age' + _coef[c3:female]+_coef[c3:_cons])
loca diffc3=`cf'-`c3m'
di "c3[OR_female - OR_male]=>" %5.3g `c3f' " -" %5.3g `c3m' " =" %5.3g `diffc3'  // "OR"=>odds ratio
```

Hopefully I am getting this right. Feel free to correct if any mistake was committed.